# If statement in Rails helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in a helper file:

```
  def admin_post_edit_destroy(post)
    if current_user.admin?
      link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post)
      link_to "delete", post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure" }
    end
  end
```

I got it to return the `delete`.

I was just wondering what do I need add to make it display the edit link in addition to the delete link? Do I type `&&` or `+` or something else?

Comment: I'd suggest making two methods--one to return an admin edit link and another to return the delete link. Then, you can just call each method directly from your view to insert the link. This will give you more flexibility to style each link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that a ruby method automatically returns only the value of the last item calculated, so you are only getting the delete link back. Try adding the two links together like this:

```
def admin_post_edit_destroy(post)
  if current_user.admin?
    link_to('Edit', edit_post_path(post)) + link_to('Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure" })
  end
end
```

You could also return two values from the helper method:

```
def admin_post_edit_destroy(post)
  if current_user.admin?
    return link_to('Edit', edit_post_path(post)), link_to('Delete', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure" })
  end
end
```

Then you can call the method like this to get the two return values in the two variables (`edit_link` and `delete_link`):

```
edit_link, delete_link = admin_post_edit_destroy(@post)
```